# Fusion360 - How do I fill these sketch planes into a body?

Tags: cad, drawings

How do I make this highlighted part of drawing a solid body so that I can than boolean / subtract it later?

All of these faces / planes are connected.

[image]

Comment: ...so are they faces, or planes? (Not the same)

Comment: Following Chris' excellent answer, it seems they were 'Patches', and not "faces / planes" at all...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are in patch mode.

Fusion has three main ways of creating solid bodies.

In the **Model** environment you can either create a solid from scratch using Create Form which creates various different solid shapes with faces whcih can be manipulated by push/pull tools.

Or also in the **model** environment you can start with a sketch and *extrude* it. as well as the basic extrude tool you can *sweep*  the shape along a path, *revolve* it around an axis or *loft* between two or more different shapes.

Alternatively in the **Patch** environment (orange coloured tool icons) you start with 2 dimensional shapes and *thicken* them. This tends to be most useful when creating complex hollow shapes.

It sounds like you need to go into the **model** environment (from the drop down menu in the top left where it says PATCH in your screenshot).

If you are trying to create a solid pyramid the easiest way might be to *loft* one of the faces to a point on one of the vertices. Alternatively you could extrude one face to the appropriate length to create a prism and then use the other faces as cutting planes for the split tool or possibly extrude them in inwards to create an *intersection*